# Upcoming termination of service to V1 of Authentication service on the Autodesk Platform Service. Questions

Tags: autodesk-forge

One of my customer send those questions below after I mentioned the V2 migration. Not sure if you could help to answer:
I have some questions:
Would this affect the Power BI connector? Since OAuth v2 was released March last year I think it’s quite likely that many have the connector from before, would it stop functioning in April then?

Other API URLs still have a v1 in it (accounts, hubs, etc) presuming that’s not changing?

Is there any plan to create a server-to-server option for the data connector? I’m still scratching my head about how to handle refresh tokens securely.